# Introspecting Child Components in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

If I have two components involved in a list:

- `my-list`
- `my-item`

But let's say actually there are two types of "items" that a list might contain so there is another component:

- `my-other-item`

At run time I instantiate my list with something like:

```
{{my-list items=items type='my-other-item'}}
```

What I'd like is that my `my-list` component be able to do some introspection on the item component that has been chosen and react appropriately. In my example, lets say that each item component has a meta-attribute called `_aspects` and I'd like to do something like:

```
if(App[type]._aspects === 'foo') { ... }
```

where 'type' is the name of the item component. Has anyone tackled this problem before?

> I've included the 'ember-cli' tag as well as 'ember' only because maybe my problems are associated with not fully understanding the CLI's resolver

Comment: Are you using ur components in the block form? Well you could register your child components to ur parent on 'init' or 'willInsertElement' using something like this.get('parentView').register(this). Here 'register' will be a method u define in the parent component which just keeps an array of child components passed in.

Comment: @blessenm yes something like this is what I was thinking. WRT to block or inline forms the answer is both. For 90% cases the inline form will be more compact and meet the needs but switching to block mode allows a richer set of options where you need them.

Comment: Is the "parentView" property always available to a component which was instantiated within the block of another component?

Comment: I think parentView is always available. Its worked for me so far. You can also use `nearestWithProperty` or 'nearestOfType' methods of component to look up the ancestors. Ben Lesh uses this technique with his components. https://github.com/blesh/ember-composable-components-example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component helper, introduced in Ember 1.11, which allows you to decide which component should render based on a bound value:   http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_component-helper

Here is an article on the subject. Option C near the bottom is what you are looking for:
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/26/emberjs-dynamically-render-components/

**[Working JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/hujohe/3/edit?html,js,output)**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.3/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>
<script src="//builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.11.3/ember.debug.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars'>
    {{my-list model=model}}  
  </script>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='components/my-list'>

    <ul>
      {{#each model as |item|}}
        {{component item.componentType tag='li' item=item}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>

  </script>

  <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='components/my-item-type1'>
    <b style='color:green'>{{item.componentType}}</b><br>
    ({{item.description}})
  </script>

    <script type='text/x-handlebars'
          data-template-name='components/my-item-type2'>
    <i style='color:orange'>{{item.componentType}}</i><br>
    ({{item.description}})
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var fixtureData = [
  {
    name: 'Item 1',
    componentType: 'my-item-type1',
    description: 'Should be rendered with component type1'
  },{
    name: 'Item 2',
    componentType: 'my-item-type2',
    description: 'Should be rendered with component type2'
  }
];

App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return fixtureData;
  }
});
```

Comment: I share you enthusiasm for the component helper and I am using it. In fact, it's because of this to some degree that I'm trying to solve this problem. You see, once you've abstracted the Item component then you need to discern which properties the underlying item cares about. So item-a component may care about a `color` and `style` property whereas item-b cares about `image` and `foobar`. What I want is for the list component to become aware of its child's needs through some mechanism. Without which you could have a lot of extra observers and parameters passed around. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I see. I don't know about your specific use case but this feels like it may be going against the grain of the framework. Could you update your question with more information about what you are hoping to acheive?

Comment: My goal is that the parent should know as little as possible about the various needs of the child components while still providing the children with the flexibility they need. The *registration* pattern introduced by @blessenm in the question comments is a standard way to solve this problem but I'm wondering if there are other ways that people recommend.

Comment: This can be done with the component helper. The child components can care about whatever they want and the parent doesn't need to know about it. As far as I'm concerned this approach does exactly what you're asking for. Hopefully someone else will come along with a totally different solution that does the same thing.

Comment: I'm not being clear ... the list DOES need to know about specifics of the item type but in a generic/reusable way. ;)

Comment: If one type of ITEM has properties A,B,C that it cares about and another has properties D,E,F then the list needs to know which properties to proxy into the item. What I'm looking for is a list to startup, ask the item what it cares about, and then deliver those properties only.

Comment: You could write your own handlebars helper based on the component helper but with the ability to pull that list of properties from a hash on the child component's backing data... just thinking out loud.